# How to implement page swipe in angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I want to add swipe feature to pages in angular. For instance, there are two pages. On swipe by a mouse cursor or touch, the next page should be displayed. I've looked into other solutions using hammer.js but it seems to be the library for mobile devices and uses touch gestures. Is there any way to implement swipe to pages in angular other than hammer.js

Comment: What's the reason why hammer js doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If the application isn't too big you could make a component for each page and then use something like [swiper](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper) to to transition between them. I have used swiper before and I am pretty sure it supports both mouse and touch.

If the application is big and there are alot of pages I would use the router to handle construction and deconstruction of the pages, unfortunately I don't know how to transition between routes using a swiper.